# Why do I get for printf format for a specific basic data type in macro?

Tags: c, macros

How to write `FORMAT_OF(type)`,so that it will be `%d` for `int`,`%s` for `char *`,etc.

Is there a macro to get the format for basic data types?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You should know the data types of the objects in your program...

Comment: @sarnold ,in my case `type` is also defined by a macro.

Comment: Until C1X you'll have to write macros that take a `fmt` along with the variable.

Comment: @Chris Lutz ,what do you mean? Can you post that as an answer? I may accept that as I can't accept the not yet supported c1x solution ...

Comment: @new_perl - Basically, instead of `PRINT(x) printf(FORMAT_OF(x), (x))` you'd have to write `PRINT(fmt, x) printf(fmt, x)`. It's more code at the caller, but it's what you're stuck with until C1X. It's not terribly helpful right now, but if you posted more about what you were trying to do I might be able to help you more.

Comment: @new_perl:
If the compiler is GCC, similar macro can be written
using `__builtin_types_compatible_p` and `__builtin_choose_expr`
like [here](http://ideone.com/1gbON).
However, format specifier and string literal cannot be mixed in this case...

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  But it is only available in C11.

```
#define FORMAT_OF(x) _Generic((x), \
    int: "%d", \
    unsigned: "%u", \
    const char *: "%s", \
    void *: "%p")
```

For types instead of values, you could try `_Generic((type) 0, ...`.

Your compiler probably does not support C11.  GCC 4.6 (but not 4.5!) has some C11 support enabled with `-std=c1x` or `-std=gnu1x`, but I don't think `_Generic` is supported yet.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: I read an article that claimed that the standard was passed with unanimous support in the penultimate vote, which means that the final vote is skipped.  I can't remember where I read the article, and I couldn't find info on the WG page.  I don't think it's been published as C11 yet, but it will be.

Comment: Awesome. Now all we have to do is wait another 10 years until they start writing a new draft for compilers to support it... (Also, shouldn't it just be `char *` instead of `const char *`? Or will `_Generic` know that my `char str[] = "This";` should match a `const char *`? Can `_Generic` be used to differentiate between `const` and non-`const` types?)

Comment: The `_Generic` macro only checks that the types are compatible, so `const char *` will catch both.  Given that C11 actually makes optional some of the mandatory C99 features, and some of the new features overlap heavily with C++11, I am cautiously optimistic about getting C11 support "relatively soon" in GCC and Clang, at least.  To my eyes, the new C11 features seem *much easier* to implement than the features new in C99.

Comment: It is reassuring to see GCC already supporting some features from C1X. It would just be nice to see modern C support be more widespread since C99 support is all over the map and has been for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

No. Currently standardized versions of C does not support type introspection of this sort.

Comment: C11 has the `_Generic` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only want the macro to take a type, you could:

```
#define FORMAT_int "%d"
#define FORMAT_char "%c"
...
#define FORMAT(x) FORMAT_##x
```

and use `FORMAT(int)` later on; but

```
int i;
FORMAT(i);
```

would **not** work, and `FORMAT(char*)` would not work either.

Answer (score -2):

There aren't any inbuilt macros in C but you could easily write a wrapper function to accomplish this.

Comment: How could you write a wrapper function, without C++?

Comment: How would you write such a function (without using C201X's `_Generic`)?

Comment: You could do this with a limited range of types (like `float` / `double` / `long double`) using `sizeof` or some other trick, but this won't work in general.

Comment: `sizeof`? That won't tell the difference between an `int` and a `char*` on most systems!

Comment: @Dave - That's why I said "with a limited range of types." That makes it unsuitable for determining `printf` formats, among other things.

Comment: Sorry but maybe I misunderstood the question. The wrapper function I was talking about is essentially for printf(). The function would essentially take in the statement you want to print and a variable argument list, parse and insert the values accordingly, ending with  only something like a single printf("%s", filledInStatement).